# Prove $z\rightarrow \mid f(z)\mid$ cannot have a local min in $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ open subset

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

We discussed in class an example for the Maximum Modulus Principle:

Prove that if the subset $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ is open, connected, $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, non constant and has nonzeros in $U$, then $z\rightarrow \mid f(z)\mid$ cannot have a local min in $U$.

Taking $1/f$, it is well-defined since, by assumption, there are no zero values of $f$, but I missed the argument why this function cannot have a minimum. Could someone please explain?

Comment: Have you looked at Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle

Comment: You don't want to show that $1/f$ cannot have a minimum! You want to show $f$ cannot have a mimimum,  which is the  same as showing _what_ about $1/f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the map $x\mapsto 1/x$ *reverses* the order of the interval $(0,\infty)$. That is, the statements $x<y$ and $\frac{1}x>\frac{1}y$ are equivalent. Thus, if you want to show that $f$ does not have a local **minimum**, you want to show that $1/f$ does not have a local **maximum** - but it sounds like you already have the maximum modulus principle, which exactly says that $1/f$ does not have a local maximum.

Comment: Actually from the statement of the theorem it is pretty clear! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the open mapping theorem. I think this gives more intuition than the maximum modulus principle.

The open mapping theorem implies that
$f(U)$ is open. If $f$ has no zeros in $U$ then $|f(U)|$ is an open interval that is a subset of $(0,\infty)$ and hence has no $\min$.

Note the distinction between $\min$ and $\inf$: For example, with $U=B(0,1)$ and $f(z) = 1-z$ that $|f(U)| = (0,1)$, that is, $\inf |f(U)| = 0$.